# Read Pandas CSV string with double quote inside

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm having problem while processing csv file like this format :

"Order ID","Order Status","Order Date", "Address", "Total"

"10000","Delivered","07/10/2020 05:44", "In front of "SUPERMAN MINIMARKET" then turn right", "10.0000"

If I'm doing : `pd.read_csv(file.csv, sep = ',')`
the result is

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 1, saw 10

The problem is occur when I have double quotes inside string in address column like "SUPERMAN MINIMARKET" with double quotes inside address value = "In front of "SUPERMAN MINIMARKET" then turn right"

Any advice of how to read this csv file?

Comment: try without `sep = ','` and provide the full name of the file including extension, something like `file.csv`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I edited the question and pinpoint the issue is in double quotes inside string values in csv files. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSVs, bless their souls, can be dodgy. Try if this works - using your path to the file instead of `StringIO(s)`:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
    
s="""
"Order ID","Order Status","Order Date","Address","Total"
"10000","Delivered","07/10/2020 05:44","In front of "SUPERMAN MINIMARKET" then turn right","10.0000"
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),
                 sep=',',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                 quotechar='"'
                )

#        Order ID Order Status        Order Date  \
# 0     10000    Delivered  07/10/2020 05:44   
#     
#                                              Address  Total  
# 0  In front of SUPERMAN MINIMARKET" then turn right"   10.0
```

Comment: Thank you it works like what I want, but now I'm facing more advance problem. When the address case turn into "In front of "SUPERMAN MINIMARKET" then turn right, St. Antonio road, Washington DC, USA", it turns out the result didn't as I expect. Can you help me about this?

Comment: What's the error you get? You should be able to have commas within the quoted string (determined by `quotechar` and those commas are ignored if they are the delimiter.