# Read csv with commas surrounded by double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file (Comma seperated) in an S3 bucket.
Few fields have commas, and the CSV file looks like this:

```
Q,W,E,R
A,S,"D,F",G
Z,X,C,V
```

When I read this in `pandas`, I should get 4 columns with `"D,F"` in one column, but I am getting an extra column.

My Code; different things I tried, but all tries did not work:

```
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd

#encoding
result = chardet.detect(self.raw_content)
self.encoding = result['encoding']

#csv_delimiter 
is being read from the DB ( , in this case)

#max_columns 
is NUMBER of columns in the csv file

#reading from s3 bucket
self.raw_content = obj['Body'].read()
content = io.BytesIO(self.raw_content)

#Try 1
df_s3_file = pd.read_csv(content, delimiter=csv_delimiter, engine='python',
    dtype=object, encoding=self.encoding, quotechar='"',
    names=list(range(0,max_columns)))

#Try 2
df_s3_file = pd.read_csv(content, delimiter=csv_delimiter, engine='python',
    dtype=object, encoding=self.encoding, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    names=list(range(0,max_columns)))

#Try 3
df_s3_file = pd.read_csv(content, delimiter=csv_delimiter, dtype=object,
    encoding=self.encoding, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    names=list(range(0,max_columns)))
```

Current Result:

```
0    1    2    4    5
Q    W    E    R    NaN
A    S    "D   F"   G
Z    X    C    V    NaN
```

Expected Result:

```
0    1    2    4
Q    W    E    R
A    S    D,F  G
Z    X    C    V
```

Answer (score 1):

You can process it with the following code (after https://stackoverflow.com/a/64456792/5660315):

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd

s="""
Q,W,E,R
A,S,"D,F",G
Z,X,C,V
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),
                 names=range(4),
                 sep=',',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                 quotechar='"'
                )
print(df)
#    0  1    2  3
# 0  Q  W    E  R
# 1  A  S  D,F  G
# 2  Z  X    C  V
```

Comment: Pandas can parse that. The problem might be with content. I don’t know the values in your variables that aren’t displayed there.

Seeing that you lost one of your double-quotes, I would check what character is representing the close-quote. pd.read_csv should parse that fine even without any of the additional parameters you have set. Note: this was an answer, but now that I have enough reputation I moved it here as a comment.

Comment: So, I tried to use quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar='"' both as parameters, but it does not seem to work. Please note that the file which I am using is on s3 and has been read as BytesIO, how can StringIO be useful for me?

Comment: `StringIO` is used to make it a code block that you can copy and run. Why are you using `BytesIO` and not just regular text to read in, anyway? Are you still getting the same dataframe with an extra column?

Comment: Well since csv is on S3 bucket, and one solution I found to read it was based on BytesIO. For StringIO, I would be needing the decode parameter, since the input CSV may have various encoding types. BytesIO works good for me, hence using that. Any sugessions?

Comment: I assumed `pd.read_csv` expects a "text-y" kind of object. Maybe not. But explicitly converting to `BytesIO` seems the wrong solution. Did you try passing your S3 object directly to `pd.read_csv`? The Pandas documentation says that it supports the S3 URL scheme for the `filepath_or_buffer` parameter.